# Why doesn't my HVAC turn on with my new thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

I am trying to replace an older Robertshaw with a Honeywell Home T5. The issue I'm running into is the home only has 3 wires leading to the thermostat: RH W G. The RH has a jumper to the RC. The new model does not need a jumper.

After installing the new thermostat it will not turn on. I've attempted to try both R wire holes and both W holes. Any help or tips would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Honeywell T5 is a smart WiFi thermostat which, like most WiFi thermostats, requires 24 volts AC power via the “C” wire. Without this extra wire, it cannot function.

Conventional programmable thermostats can often function using internal batteries but the WiFi electronics need too much power.

To make the T5 function, you will need to run an extra wire for power back to your furnace (assuming your furnace has a 24 volt terminal) or use Honeywell’s free offer for a C wire adapter (available per the user manual I found online).